# Align key-value pairs in two columns

Tags: python

So I have this code:

```
food={'banana': 3, 'fish': 10, 'pineapple': 1, 'apple': 7}

print("Food       "+"Amount")
for x in food:
    print (x,end="       ")
    print (food[x])
```

The output is this:

```
Food       Amount
banana       3
fish       10
pineapple       1
apple       7
```

But how can make the numbers line up like this:

```
Food       Amount
banana       3
fish         10
pineapple    1
apple        7
```

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: `print(f"{x:>15}  {food[x]:>10")` would be one option. Look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec  for center, left/right alignment etc.

Comment: `print('\n'.join(  f"{a:<10} {b:^5}" for a,b in ([("Food","Amount")] + [i for i in food.items()]) ))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
food={'banana': 3, 'fish': 10, 'pineapple': 1, 'apple': 7}
print(f"{'Food':<12}Amount")
for key, val in food.items():
    print(f"{key:<12}  {val}")
```

Comment: may I ask what does `f"` do in the print statment?

Comment: the `f` at the beginning turns it into an "f-string" allowing the use of Python expressions between `{` and `}` within the string. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html